# Mac no longer recognizes .py files?

Tags: python, macos

I usually code on Atom, and recently, my Mac has just started to stop recognizing .py files as python files. It always recognizes those files now as TextEdit files, so that I can't even run the file without copy pasting the code into another file that my computer recognizes as a python file to run the code. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can just run the file from Terminal or from a terminal package within Atom.

Comment: This is probably more of a question for Super User or AskDifferent than for Stack Overflow, because it's the same question as, e.g., when JPG files start opening in CrappyPaint instead of Preview, and there are probably much better Mac Finder experts over there than here.

Comment: However, I'm pretty sure if you just Get Info on a Python file, open the "Open With" disclosure triangle, change the pulldown from TextEdit to Atom, then click the button that says "Use this application to open all documents like this one", that will do it.

Comment: Dups from [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/29016/how-to-change-file-associations-on-mac-os-x), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45491/how-to-change-file-type-associations), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28893/how-can-i-manually-change-default-applications-in-os-x), [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/17761/file-association-for-editing-on-a-mac), [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/20822/where-does-mac-os-x-store-file-association-information)